# Can't get current author avatar in posts

Tags: php, wordpress, avatar, author

For some reason `get_avatar($user_email, 125);` doesn't work. I can't figure out why. This is my code in `single.php`:

```
<?php
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
    $user_email = $curauth->user_email;
?>

  <div class="author-box clearfix">
      <img class="author" src="<?php echo get_avatar($user_email, 125); ?> " width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo the_author_meta( 'display_name' , $author_id ); ?>" />
        <h4 class="title"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></h4>
        <p class="title"><?php the_author_meta( 'title' ); ?></p>
        <p class="info"><strong>M: </strong><?php the_author_meta( 'user_email' ); ?></p>
        <p class="info"><strong>W: </strong><a href="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url' ); ?>"><?php the_author_meta( 'user_url' ); ?></a></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [get_avatar](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/) documentation, it returns the entire image element string.

> Retrieve the avatar `<img>` tag for a user, email address, MD5 hash, comment, or post.

The way you're using it, you'd want the image url, so use [get_avatar_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/).

> Return: (false|string) The URL of the avatar we found, or false if we couldn't find an avatar.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email'), '90' );
```

learn to create your own author box [here](http://goo.gl/yNXdkT)